# How to remove space between app activity and navigation bar?

Tags: android, android-studio

Screenshot was taken on Xiamoni Redmi Note5

[image: Screenshot was taken on Xiamoni Redmi Note5]

In the emulator, this problem has not happened.
please help me.

[image: XMl file]

Comment: Please upload your layout.xml

Comment: Is this a native app?

Comment: @MidasLefko please see the XML file.

Comment: Sorry i don't know what is native app.

Comment: please do not use screenshots to provide code snippets or layouts as this makes it more difficult to test your code. In other words, do not expect any help if we have to do more work then necessary to help you find a solution to your issue. Edit your post and add the xml layout in text form.

Comment: You are a stackoverflow beginner so you probably didnt know, but @Barns is right. In the future, instead of uploading a screenshot of your layout you should copy and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CatalogActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    // etc rest if the layout is the same
```

Comment: match_parent not work. N.B: It works on emulator but does not work in a Physical device.

Comment: what do you mean "it doesnt work"? Doesnt compile? Has unexpected output? Please explain...

Comment: It has been compiled without error.But the space problem didn't solve.

Comment: You set match_parent to RelativeLayout AND ListView? You removed padding from ListView?

Comment: That problem only occurred in a large device like Xiamoni Redmi Note 5(display size 5.99'')